# Vuetify update select input-value by prepend-item event

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'd like to update the select value by clicking the prepended item in a Vuetify select. But the model doesn't update the item-text in the select input.

```
<v-select
 :items="loadedTasks"
 v-model="selectedTask"
 item-text="text"
 item-value="value"
 return-object
 :menu-props="{closeOnContentClick: true}"
>
 <template v-slot:prepend-item>
   <v-list-item
    @click="selectedTask = {text:'none', value: 'none'}"
   >
    Text
   </v-list-item>
 </template>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add some "default" item to the select, the `prepend-slot` is no way to go as it cannot be "selected". It's better to just add your "default" item directly into the `loadedTasks` array

For example using computed:

```js
computed: {
  tasksToSelect() {
    return [{text:'none', value: 'none'}, ...this.loadedTasks]
  }
}
```

...and use it like `<v-select :items="tasksToSelect" />`

Comment: I just removed the prepended item... there was no way to set the first option to display:none... changed the first item in loadedTasks to show up like the prepended item... thx!